# How to include WTelegramClient session to program executable file for security

Tags: c#, session, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I'm using WTelegramClient for connecting to telegram api.
I want to public my application to anyone can use it, my application connected to a user in telegram and i want to all of my app users can use my application with that telegram user that i provided in my app.
Now my question is how to include session data to program executable file to be hidden for security. Actually, I don't want the file to be public so that everyone can connect to Telegram using that file, only my app can use that to connect to telegram when it open and do not ask for any user authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram API is not intended to be used by several people connecting to the same Telegram user account.

Usually when you distribute an application for Telegram, each user would use their own phone number, and you just distribute your api_id/api_hash that is specific to your application.

If you really want to offer a system where many of your users need to go through the same Telegram account, maybe the best approach would be to offer your service as a web api.
Your users would connect to that web app (in browser or an executable connecting to it) and your critical Telegram session data remains on the web server side of the web api.